# Why i cant make 2 backgrounds in a whole page html/css

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a website and had an error; I cant make 2 backgrounds in a singular html page: I want to make it so that the header, footer and the body have separate backgrounds but the element repeats when it specifies in the CSS 'no-repeat. Here is the code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(image/stacks.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#web {
  border: solid 3px;
  width: 460px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 33px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-image: url(https://th.bing.com/th? 
 id=OIF.X08wRmGQAg%2bBkQmjrlRbWQ&w=348&h=143&c=7&r=0&o=5&pid=1.7);
  color: white;
}

#mar {
  border: solid 3px;
  width: 230px;
  background-color: tomato;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  background-image: url(https://th.bing.com/th? 
 id=OIF.X08wRmGQAg%2bBkQmjrlRbWQ&w=348&h=143&c=7&r=0&o=5&pid=1.7);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#OK {
  border: solid 3px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: tomato;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url(https://th.bing.com/th? 
 id=OIF.X08wRmGQAg%2bBkQmjrlRbWQ&w=348&h=143&c=7&r=0&o=5&pid=1.7);
}

#HI {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 23px;
  background-image: url(https://th.bing.com/th? 
 id=OIF.X08wRmGQAg%2bBkQmjrlRbWQ&w=348&h=143&c=7&r=0&o=5&pid=1.7);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-image: url(https://th.bing.com/th? 
 id=OIF.X08wRmGQAg%2bBkQmjrlRbWQ&w=348&h=143&c=7&r=0&o=5&pid=1.7);
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#hehe {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

ul {
  float: left;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  background-image: url(https://th.bing.com/th? 
 id=OIF.X08wRmGQAg%2bBkQmjrlRbWQ&w=348&h=143&c=7&r=0&o=5&pid=1.7);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta keywords="htmls,tech,learn" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>t3lem_تعليم</title>


</head>



<body>
  <div id="hehe">
    <ul>
      <li> Home</li>
      <li> <a href="youtube.html">   الفيديوهات    </a></li>


      <li> اتصل بنا</li>

      <li> عن الموقع</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="HI">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCi0k9ygpc-NXOL090pIUkuw/"> <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/4qs1rBAWeor-sAeiNr9fDSHw4dtpF6--drGr70O_xAhA5Zq9LVSZAPe- 
        vuiVIzRKIxwvlF5Evw=s600-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj-rp-mo" width="80px"> </a>
    العودة للقناة
  </div>


  <div id="wrapper">




    <div id="web">



      Welocme to T3leem_Website



    </div>

    <div id="mar">
      أهلا بكم في موقع تعليم




    </div>
    <div id="OK">
      الصفحة الرئيسية

    </div>

  </div>

</body>








</html>
```

I cant put 2 backgrounds and wanted to know why. *I tried methods but nothing seems to work* in HTML/CSS
I hope you can answer my question
and  thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Read this to understand more about specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp) .

And you can use one of the following things :

- either add `!important` to  `background-repeat: no-repeat;` in this way :
  `*{background-repeat: no-repeat !important;}`
- or you can add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to individual element which are using  `background-image` property

Comment: ok , but i want how to make double images in whole page

Comment: I don't get what you want to do , can you provide any image of what you want to do and what are you getting

Comment: i want to put a photo on top and photo on center and ...

Comment: To do that just make the number of boxes using elment (like `div`,`span`,whatever you like) specify their `width: 100%; display: block; height : according to need` . Then just apply background image to specific elements